Regex positive lookahead not working as expected

I want to extract the following string:
/e670d0d1-bcf2-47f7-879b-64ab40600ff8-u1/mask_00005.png

from this test string:
https://s3.us-east-005.backblazeb2.com/ph/e670d0d1-bcf2-47f7-879b-64ab40600ff8-u1/mask_00005.png?X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Credential=005dc68faa31bb70000000004%2F20240417%2Fus-east-1%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Date=20240417T092401Z&X-Amz-Expires=604800&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&X-Amz-Signature=a82f66f63086597ab49651ba91edb31133875d64415ecb54317c8766df0b0950

(?<=https:\/\/s3\.us-east-005\.backblazeb2\.com\/ph)(.*)(?=\?X-Amz-Algorithm)

Tried on https://regex101.com/ but it doesn't return anything and I don't understand why.

javascript. added the tag. It's part of a platform I'm using so I'm limited to regex javascript

Have you selected some non-default setting on regex101? Because it shows me exactly what you want given the input data in the question.

There is /gm flag by default

What is with the flags? See https://regex101.com/r/v2rrW4/1/codegen?language=javascript. Compare to yours.

@CalvinKao The screenshot doesn't show the part over on the right where both Match 1 and Group 1 contain the result you want.

just updated screenshot

Looks like you have a carriage return at the end of your regex in your regex101 example. See the little left return arrow in the  image you posted?

You have a line break at the end of your pattern in the regex101. Typo.

I'm new to stackoverflow. Is there a way to "upvote" or give credit to the right answers?

You will find the answer to the question posed in your last comment, and to others you may have about stackoverflow, here. Specifically, click on "View more" under "Asking" then click on "What should I do when someone answers my question?". In general, you should wait a few hours before selecting an answer, to allow members ample time to submit them. (There's no rush.) Also, don't select an answer if none are helpful and keep in mind that you can always change your selection if a better answer is posted after you have selected one.

You can use a UUID regex as a base, and tack-on the subpath -\w{2}\/ and filename (\w+\.[a-z]+).
const uuidRegex = /[0-9a-f]{8}(?:-[0-9a-f]{4}){3}-[0-9a-f]{12}/

Also, you can use a positive look-ahead (?=<?) to stop at the query param start.


const url = 'https://s3.us-east-005.backblazeb2.com/ph/e670d0d1-bcf2-47f7-879b-64ab40600ff8-u1/mask_00005.png?X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Credential=005dc68faa31bb70000000004%2F20240417%2Fus-east-1%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Date=20240417T092401Z&X-Amz-Expires=604800&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&X-Amz-Signature=a82f66f63086597ab49651ba91edb31133875d64415ecb54317c8766df0b0950'

const regex = /\/([0-9a-f]{8}(?:-[0-9a-f]{4}){3}-[0-9a-f]{12})-\w{2}\/(\w+\.[a-z]+)(?=<?)/;
const target = '/e670d0d1-bcf2-47f7-879b-64ab40600ff8-u1/mask_00005.png';

const [found, uuid, filename] = url.match(regex);

console.log(found);
console.log(found === target); // true
console.log(uuid);             // e670d0d1-bcf2-47f7-879b-64ab40600ff8
console.log(filename);         // mask_00005.png



A better choice would be to avoid using a regular expression, and parse the URL:


const url = 'https://s3.us-east-005.backblazeb2.com/ph/e670d0d1-bcf2-47f7-879b-64ab40600ff8-u1/mask_00005.png?X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Credential=005dc68faa31bb70000000004%2F20240417%2Fus-east-1%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Date=20240417T092401Z&X-Amz-Expires=604800&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&X-Amz-Signature=a82f66f63086597ab49651ba91edb31133875d64415ecb54317c8766df0b0950'

const { pathname } = new URL(url);
const expected = '/e670d0d1-bcf2-47f7-879b-64ab40600ff8-u1/mask_00005.png'
const actual = pathname.substring(pathname.indexOf('/', 1));

console.log(actual === expected); // true



